"Cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once" in if/else block
I'm building a recursive trie structure in Rust and have a routine that returns the child node given a symbol id. To complicate this, my trie node is implemented as an enum to optimize for the sparseness of the node as nodes near the root tend to be dense but with long strings of sparse nodes following. This starts off as Inline, which can hold a small fixed number of child links, or is upgraded to Sparse when the limits of Inline are exceeded.
Total symbol count is large, in the tens of thousands.
Playground link here.
My helper routine should return Ok(&mut child) on success or Err(&mut self) if no space was found in the current Inline node:
impl TrieNode
    /// return the child node on Ok, or Err with self if room can't be found in 
    /// current node variant
    fn maybe_get_child_mut(&mut self, symbol: u16) -> Result<&mut Self, &mut Self> {
        match self {
            TrieNode::Inline(inline) => {
                if let Some(child) = inline.maybe_get_child_mut(symbol) {
                    return Ok(child);
                }
            }
            TrieNode::Sparse(sparse) => return Ok(sparse.get_child_mut(symbol)),
        }
        
        Err(self)
    }
}

But I get this borrow error:
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:85:13
   |
75 |     fn maybe_get_child_mut(&mut self, symbol: u16) -> Result<&mut Self, &mut Self> {
   |                            - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
76 |         match self {
77 |             TrieNode::Inline(inline) => {
   |                              ------ first mutable borrow occurs here
78 |                 if let Some(child) = inline.maybe_get_child_mut(symbol) {
79 |                     return Ok(child);
   |                            --------- returning this value requires that `self.0` is borrowed for `'1`
...
85 |         Err(self)
   |             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

It appears that the &mut borrow is held for the duration of the routine even when inner function call returns None and falls out of scope. The code compiles if I comment out the return on line 79. This is a bit surprising to me since only one or the other &mut references are held and their lifetimes are compatible as one is a subset of the other.
Any help on how to cure this code is appreciated. Ugly hacks are also acceptable as long as safety is not compromised ;-).

Polonius strikes again. Try moving Err(self) under Inline as else { return Err(self); }.

@ChayimFriedman That resulted in the same compiler error. Is there a good write up on Polonius that I can refer to? The problem seems to be in this case that I've borrowed the inner member of the enum and can't get that out of scope. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dc6b020c3b2c3008f6400c912960791d

Ok, found a write up on Polonius here: https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2023/10/06/polonius-update.html

This has been closed, but here's a solution that uses two unsafe blocks to work around the limitations of the current borrow checker. tl;dr convert the &mut to a pointer and then back to a &mut on each branch. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=806ba5116988bb212b764a7b2ad33d09
